# C/C++, are objects binary compatible across platform?

Tags: memory, cross-platform

I would like to send some object data, in binary, across some mcu. I treat it as a cross platform problem. How I would like to implement is like:

```
//mcu A
//someObj declared and initialized
Send((uint_8_t*)&someObj,sizeof(someObj));

//mcu B
SomeClass someObj;
Read((uint_8_t*)&someObj,sizeof(someObj));
```

Are there any guarantee in C/C++ that such thing is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guaranty that it works. If your data is only composed of a set of chars, it will probably work whatever the platforms.

Otherwise, you will encounter hardware and software problems.

Hardware problems include endianness and data alignment.

Endianness refers to the way multibyte data types are arranged in memory. For instance an integer has 4 bytes and some architectures store it in memory by writing at the lowest address address the least significant byte (little endian like the pentium) while others store the most significant byte at the lowest address (big endian).  If endianness is different, bytes must be swapped to ensure compatibility. Note that some platforms (Arm, mips, among others) can use both endianness, but it is generally selected at boot time. Also some machines have different endianness for integers and floats.

Alignment refers to the constraint on many architectures that a 2^k bytes data must be at an address multiple of 2^k. Some architectures, like the pentium, do not have this constraint and can manipulate unaligned data, but a compiler may lay out data in an aligned way to improve performances. As a side effect of alignment constraints, a given object may not have the same size on different architectures and sizeof() applied to a struct is not guaranteed to return the same value.

Software problems are related to the nature of your data.
Obviously if your data contains any kind of pointer, it is impossible to transfer them as is across platforms.
If you have C++ objects with constructors/destructors, again you will run into problems if transferring binary data.

The process of converting data to allow a safe transfer across platforms is frequently called *serialization* or *pickling*. Many languages (java, javascript, python, R) have a native support for it. In C/C++, there is no support for serialization in the language, and custom serialization must written, but frameworks like Boost or MFC provide serialization methods. You can also have a look at XDR (external data representation) that is a serialization standard which is supported by several libraries.